# How can I output the values in an array to a View in MVC with Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable

## Task

Output the values from an IEnumerable of simple types in a view.

## Conditions

I have a model, passed in by the controller, that contains an array of simple values (in this case int).  I want to output it into a variable in a JavaScript block in the view.

## Standards

Without using a large foreach block and iterating over each item and then figuring out the commas, output the values in such a way that is similar to the statement seen below.

## Example

```
var packageSummaryViewModel = new PackageSummaryViewModel([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
```

Currently this is what is happening:

### View.cshtml

```
var packageSummaryViewModel = new PackageSummaryViewModel(@sensorIds);
```

### Output

```
var packageSummaryViewModel = new PackageSummaryViewModel(System.Int32[]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I do this is to use a JSON serializer, like JSON.NET. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so it's natural to use a JSON serializer to convert C#/.NET objects to Javascript objects.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model MyNamespace.MyObject

var myProperty = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.MyProperty));
```

If `Model.MyProperty` is a `List<int>` containing the integers `1, 2, 3`, Razor will render this as follows:

```
var myProperty = [1,2,3];
```

If `Model.MyProperty` is an instance of the following class

```
class C
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

with `X` set to `apple` and `Y` set to `0.5`, Razor will render this as follows:

```
var myProperty = {"X":"apple","Y":0.5};
```

The point is that this same approach works for any JSON-serializable C#/.NET object you might be passing as your model (or part of your model).

Comment: Well then why the heck did it take me 45 minutes to drag the below solution out of a bunch of guys who purport themselves to be MVC knowledgeable?

Comment: @CodeWarrior This is such an extremely common operation, rendering a C#/.NET object into a JS script as a literal. I can't speak to why it took them so long - maybe they still have some things to learn. :) Your guys *did* end up showing you how to render an `IEnumerable<int>` as JSON, but their solution is poor in that it implements JSON serialization in part. What if you want to serialize an `IEnumerable<string>`? A custom object? A `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`? Clearly you should be using a general-purpose JSON serializer for this purpose.

Comment: Indeed.I think I am going to delete my "answer" and vote yours up.